# Javascript : Replace url between href tag

Tags: node.js, regex

I am trying to replace urls between the href tag but unfortunately i don't know the javascript equivalent of

```
(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))
```

Javascript is missing the positive look behind.

Any idea how i can achieve this please ? Thank you !

Comment: Just have to post when people use reg exp on html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: If you show a larger context for what you're trying to do, we can perhaps offer better ways to solve this problem than using a regex (such as using the DOM API or an actual HTML parser).  This question is kind of like "I'm down this narrow path of a solution to a larger problem and ran into this dead-end.  How do I solve this dead-end?" when, in reality, there are probably other ways to solve the problem that don't go down this dead-end.  But, without sharing the overall problem you're trying to solve, you've make it so we can't offer our best help.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an attribute on the anchor element:

```js
function magic(){
    var a=document.getElementById("anchor");
    a.href="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="anchor">Trallala</a>
<button onclick="magic()">Pushme</button>
```

EDIT: Apparently links are not very welcome in these code snippets, but you can check the change via hovering, and you can also open the link in a new window/tab

Answer (score 0):

In general, trying to modify HTML with regular expressions is really difficult, dangerous, and hard to maintain. You'll have a much better time using a HTML manipulation library like jQuery:

```
<a id='myLink' href='http://fish.com'></a>

var $link= $("'#myLink");
$link.attr("href", "http://melons.com');
```